# Dynamically generate a PDF using existing data and design using Vuejs

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I would like to know if this is possible. I am trying to create a form and that takes in name, expiry, picture, and on submit generates a PDF with the details provided.

The PDF would have an existing design created by me and I want these details to go and update on a specific location on the pdf.

Is this possible? if so, how do I go about it?

I have been exploring jsPDF and html2pdf...

Comment: You can look into paged.js as well, very simple to use and works well with existing css/html https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vue-html2pdf` or `jspdf`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

And it seems you are using Laravel for the backend.
Regardless of whether it is any other language such as Java or Python, it may be another option to generate PDF files on the server side, not the client side.